# How to filter DataFrame using isna?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This seems super basic and yet I am failing to filter this dataframe. As you can see from the screenshot I load a very basic set of data. I check if any values in column 'Col3' is na. And finally I try to filter the dataframe using that. I am hoping to get returned just the second column (with index 1). But as you can see I get all 5 rows but the values for Col3 are now all NaN.

I am using Python 3.7.3 and Pandas 1.1.4

[image]

Trying wwnde's suggestion to use brackets instead of .loc did not seem to work:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

data( now that you didnt give me sample data)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'group2': [2, 2, 3, 4],
                   'base': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'x1': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'x2': [np.nan, 6, np.nan, 8]})



df[df['x2'].isna()]

      group1  group2  base  x1  x2
0       0       2     0     3  NaN
2       1       3     2     5  NaN
```

Use loc accessor if you need to call particular columns

```
df.loc[df['x2'].isna(),:'base']#base and preceding columns



    group1  group2  base
0       0       2     0
2       1       3     2
```

or

```
df.loc[df['x2'].isna(),['base','x1']]

    base  x1
0     0   3
2     2   5
```

Comment: That unfortunately produced the same result - see my edit

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: Python 3.7.3 and Pandas 1.1.4

Comment: See my edits. Happy to use your data if you provide a sample.